# How can I get an average

Tags: php, average

I am new on this. I have an exercise which states that a given string, I need to get the average amount of words on a sentence. So far I've done this:

```
    $sentenceArray = preg_split('/[.]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    foreach ($sentenceArray as $sentence) {
        $numberOfWords = str_word_count($sentence);
```

this gives me as a result, the number of words in 5 sentences: 16, 14, 16, 18, 17).
My issue is I don't know how to get the average of that result.
So far I did this and I only get 00000:

```
        $results[]= $numberOfWords;
        $count = count($numberOfWords);
        $sum = array_sum($numberOfWords);
     $average = $sum/ $count;
     echo $average;
```

Comment: Is the second code inside the `foreach` loop or outside?

Comment: `$numberOfWords` is the number of words - `count($numberOfWords)` would expect an array (as does `array_sum`).

Comment: Side note: are you certain that every sentence in your text will end on a full-stop?

Comment: what about ```$average = array_sum($results) / count($results)```?

Comment: Make that `$numberOfWords += str_word_count($sentence);` (and properly initialize the variable with 0 before the loop), then you have the overall number of words summed up already. Divide by `count($sentence)` after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like below:

```
$sentenceArray = preg_split('/[.]+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$totalCount = 0; //create a variable of total words count
foreach ($sentenceArray as $sentence) {
    $totalCount += str_word_count($sentence);//add count to variable
}
echo $avg = $totalCount/count($sentenceArray);//get the average
```

Sample output: https://3v4l.org/8BYDF